# Getting duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

The screenshot contains of 3 tables all connected with other

[image: The image contains of 3 tables all connected with other]

The second screenshot shows the SQL query and the result obtained:

[image: The second image consists of the sql query and the result obtained]

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t.topic_id
    , t.topic_name
    , t.topic_cover
    , t.topic_viewers
    , t1.subscribe_id 
FROM 
    tbltopic t 
INNER JOIN 
    tblsubject_grade tg ON (t.subject_garde_id = tg.subject_garde_id) 
INNER JOIN 
    tblsubcription t1 ON (tg.subject_garde_id = t1.subject_garde_id)
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: only 2 rows should be display instead of 4

Comment: Sorry you need to clearly look at your screen prints and figure this out.

Comment: Yes they say there should be only 2 rows; they don't tell us which, @DougCoats .

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issue is you have multiple JOIN conditions across a couple of tables

Check this image:
[image]

You ll see that table tblsubject_grade JOINS to BOTH the other tables.

Youre query should be:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#topic') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #topic
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#subjGrade') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #subjGrade;
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#subscription') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #subscription;

CREATE TABLE #topic (topic_id int, topic_name varchar(20), topic_cover varchar(20), topic_viewers int, teacher_id int, subject_garde_id int);
CREATE TABLE #subjGrade (subject_garde_id INT, grade_id INT, subject_id INT);
CREATE TABLE #subscription (subscribe_id INT, sub_status INT, sub_date date, student_id INT, archive_status INT, teacher_id int, subject_garde_id int);

INSERT INTO #topic (topic_id, topic_name, topic_cover, topic_viewers, teacher_id, subject_garde_id)
VALUES
(4, 'numbers',  'somestring', 0,2,1),
(6, 'shapes',   'somestring', 0,9,1),
(7, 'story time', 'somestring', 0, 2, 5)

INSERT INTO #subjGrade (subject_garde_id , grade_id , subject_id)
VALUES
(1, 1,  1),
(2, 1,  2),
(3, 1,  3),
(4, 2,  1),
(5, 2,  2),
(6, 2,  3),
(7, 2,  4),
(8, 3,  1)


INSERT INTO #subscription (subscribe_id, sub_status, sub_date, student_id, archive_status , teacher_id , subject_garde_id)
VALUES
(2, 1,  '9-7-2021', 1,0,9,1),
(3, 1,  '9-7-2021', 1,0,2,1)

SELECT
    t.topic_id
    , t.topic_name
    , t.topic_cover
    , t.topic_viewers
    , t1.subscribe_id 
FROM #topic t 
INNER JOIN #subjGrade tg ON t.subject_garde_id = tg.subject_garde_id 
INNER JOIN #subscription t1 ON 
     tg.subject_garde_id = t1.subject_garde_id
     AND t1.subject_garde_id = t.subject_garde_id 
     AND t.teacher_id = t1.teacher_id
```

Comment: still the same output

Comment: @MTB I missed a join, try it again

Comment: yes you need to remove this line AND tl.student_id = tg.student_id

Comment: @MTB I was busy making the data set locally to test - yes I messed up subject_id for student_id, which you caught. Give a guy a correct answer and an upvote please